# Link that opens a copy of a document work in Google Chrome, but not IE 11

Tags: office-integration, ie

The below code works great in Google Chrome, but not IE11.

Note in both browsers I am clicking on the open button.

- In IE11 as an example if I process the link I get an option to Open or Save and if I click on Open it says PowerPoint had a problem with the content and to repair.  Repair does nothing.
- In Google Chrome I also get an Open button and I have no issue it opens the document fine in PowerPoint.

My goal is I want users to open the document in IE without having to save the document.

In addition is there any way that I can change the URL so it does not open the document in the SharePoint library, but rather opens the document locally?

```
http://<your site collection url>/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=<your file url>
```

Comment: this behavior is for .ppt or .pptx file or both ?

Answer (score 0):

In case this happens to someone else you need to go to Trusted Setting in PowerPoint and uncheck all the settings